# A prepared statment gives no errors and not work

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I am new to php and prepared stamenents.
I am building a sql insert from a array of key, values pairs.
The code below does not give any errors (it is inside a try/catch block) and not add the data to the database also.
What is wrong with it ?

```
try {
    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    echo "new device, add it to DB\n";
    $keys = implode(", ", array_keys($header));
    $values = implode(", ", array_values($header));
    var_dump($values);

    $placeHolders = str_repeat('?,', count($header));
    $placeHolders = substr($placeHolders, 0, -1); //remove the last comma

    $sql = "INSERT INTO device ($keys) VALUES ($placeHolders);";
    echo "sql: $sql\n";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($values);
    $stmt->debugDumpParams();
 } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error adding a new device. debugParams:\n";
    $stmt->debugDumpParams();
    echo "exception: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
 }
```

The current output is:

```
string(130) "608a242b, 7f019a0be51680cb0ecb1b627415c92a, 902b3438d2cf, whatever, 1.0, 1.0, A, 0000681c0ec2, OID_GENERIC, 1563290266, 1563290266"
sql: INSERT INTO device (deviceID, scannerID, scannerMAC1, scannerMAC2, scannerVer, scannerHwRev, scannerModel, upsMAC, snmpSet, firstSeem, lastSeen) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
SQL: [176] INSERT INTO device (deviceID, scannerID, scannerMAC1, scannerMAC2, scannerVer, scannerHwRev, scannerModel, upsMAC, snmpSet, firstSeem, lastSeen) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
Params:  0
```

and the device table is empty (no rows) and it looks like this:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| deviceID     | varchar(8)  | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |
| scannerID    | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| scannerMAC1  | varchar(12) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| scannerMAC2  | varchar(12) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| scannerVer   | varchar(5)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| scannerHwRev | varchar(5)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| scannerModel | varchar(5)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| upsMAC       | varchar(12) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| snmpSet      | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| lastSeen     | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| firstSeen    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

PS: User "Don't panic" warned me I should use an array in execute argument. Using the $header as parameter to execute, now I am getting the following error:

```
string(130) "608a242b, 7f019a0be51680cb0ecb1b627415c92a, 902b3438d2cf, whatever, 1.0, 1.0, A, 0000681c0ec2, OID_GENERIC, 1563292682, 1563292682"
sql: INSERT INTO device (deviceID, scannerID, scannerMAC1, scannerMAC2, scannerVer, scannerHwRev, scannerModel, upsMAC, snmpSet, firstSeem, lastSeen) VALUES (0);
Error adding a new device. debugParams:
SQL: [156] INSERT INTO device (deviceID, scannerID, scannerMAC1, scannerMAC2, scannerVer, scannerHwRev, scannerModel, upsMAC, snmpSet, firstSeem, lastSeen) VALUES (0);
Params:  11
Key: Name: [9] :deviceID
paramno=-1
name=[9] ":deviceID"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [10] :scannerID
paramno=-1
name=[10] ":scannerID"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [12] :scannerMAC1
paramno=-1
name=[12] ":scannerMAC1"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [12] :scannerMAC2
paramno=-1
name=[12] ":scannerMAC2"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [11] :scannerVer
paramno=-1
name=[11] ":scannerVer"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [13] :scannerHwRev
paramno=-1
name=[13] ":scannerHwRev"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [13] :scannerModel
paramno=-1
name=[13] ":scannerModel"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [7] :upsMAC
paramno=-1
name=[7] ":upsMAC"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [8] :snmpSet
paramno=-1
name=[8] ":snmpSet"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [10] :firstSeem
paramno=-1
name=[10] ":firstSeem"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [9] :lastSeen
paramno=-1
name=[9] ":lastSeen"
is_param=1
param_type=2
exception: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Comment: `$values` should be an array when you use it with `execute()`. You don't need to implode it.

Comment: I need to implode it to extract the keys/values pairs and build up the insert statement. Anyway, you right, I need to use an array on execute. so it is $header. Now I am getting errors (which is a good thing, btw): "SQL: [156] INSERT INTO device (deviceID, scannerID, scannerMAC1, scannerMAC2, scannerVer, scannerHwRev, scannerModel, upsMAC, snmpSet, firstSeem, lastSeen) VALUES (0);" and "exception: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: You do need to implode the keys to build the sql, but the values should be kept in array form.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. You can't use `$header` directly. You do still need to do `array_values` to get rid of the string keys. Just don't implode the result of that. So `$values = array_values($header);`, then `$stmt->execute($values);` as in your original code.

Comment: Thank you @Don't Panic, "$values = array_values($header); fixed my code. 
It is running now ! Cheers !